# PHP: Get Value from Radio Boxes

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, radio-button

I am making a quiz where there is no correct answer and instead personalities will be compared and calculated to create a matching algorithm. So far I have:

[image]

I have 3 tables involving the quiz: questions, question_answers, question_choices:

```
questions:
+-------------+---------------+
| question_id | question      |
+-------------+---------------+
| 1           | Is your...    |
| 2           | Do you..      |
| 3           | Have you...   |
|_____________|_______________|

question_choices:
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| choice_id   | question_id | choice_text |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | 1           | Somewhere.. |
| 2           | 1           | Somewhere.. |
| 3           | 1           | Somewhere.. |
| 4           | 2           | Yes         |
| 5           | 2           | No          |
| 6           | 3           | Yes         |
| 7           | 3           | No          |
|_____________|_____________|_____________|

question_answers:
+------------+---------+------------+------------+
| answer_id  | user_id |question_id | choice_id  |
+------------+---------+------------+------------+
| 1          | 125     | 1          | 2          | 
| 2          | 3       | 1          | 3          | --> 125 & 3 = No Match
| 3          | 125     | 2          | 1          |
| 4          | 3       | 2          | 1          | --> 125 & 3 = Match
|____________|_________|____________|____________|
```

I am now working on trying to get all relative information to post to the empty question_answers table. However, I am having difficulty extracting the value of the choices selected and when clicking submit, only the option clicked for the last question (question 3) appears for all questions.

How do I tailor this for each individual question and how would I post all three of these results to the database using UPDATE?

```
<?php
$choices = (choices());
$questions = (questions());
$questions_id = (questions_id());
$questions_length = count(questions());
for ($i = 0; $i < $questions_length; $i++){
    $each_q = $questions[$i];
    $each_q_id = $questions_id[$i];
?>


<div class="poll">
    <div class="poll_question">
        <?php echo $each_q_id . ". " . $each_q; ?>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="poll_options">
            <div class="poll_option">


                <?php
                    $each_c = $choices[$i];
                    $choices_length = count($each_c);
                    for ($k = 0; $k < $choices_length; $k++){

                    $each_c = explode('<br />', $each_c);
                ?>

                <input type="radio" name="$each_c" value="1" id="c1">
                <label for="c1"><?php echo $each_c[0]; ?></label>
                <input type="radio" name="$each_c" value="2" id="c2">
                <label for="c2"><?php echo $each_c[1]; ?></label>
                <?php if (!empty($each_c[2]) === true){ ?>
                <input type="radio" name="$each_c" value="3" id="c3">
                <label for="c2"><?php echo $each_c[2]; ?></label>

                <?php    
                }}

                    $data = $_POST;
                    $each_cc = count($each_c);
                    print_r($session_user_id);
                    $option = 0;
                    if(isset($data['$each_c'])){
                    $option = $data['$each_c'];
                    echo "--".$each_q_id."--".$each_cc."--". $option. "<br>";
                } 

                ?>              
        </div>
    </form> 
<?php

}
?>
```

Functions:

```
function choices(){
    $query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT `question`, GROUP_CONCAT(`choice_text` ORDER BY `choice_text` DESC SEPARATOR '<br />') as `choice_texts` FROM `questions` JOIN `question_choices` ON questions.question_id = question_choices.question_id GROUP BY `question`");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $rows[] = $row;}
    if (count($rows)>0){
        foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
            $c[] = $value['choice_texts'];
        }
        return $c;}else return false;
}

function questions_id(){
    $query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT `question_id` FROM `questions` WHERE DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN `start` AND `end`");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $rows[] = $row;}
    if (count($rows)>0){
        foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
            $q_id = $value['question_id'];
            $array_q[] = ($q_id);
        }
        return $array_q;}else return false;
}

function questions(){
    $query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT `question` FROM `questions` WHERE DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN `start` AND `end`");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $rows[] = $row;}
    if (count($rows)>0){
        foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
            $q = $value['question'];
            $array_q[] = $q;
        }
        return $array_q;}else return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for wanting to mark the question as solved, and supplying a solution. However, we don't edit questions to do this: by overwriting the question with the solution, the continuity of the Q&A format is lost, and the result is not likely to help future visitors. If you wish to report on your solution, please make a self-answer. I have done this for you just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think in your code you create for every question different form (that is in the first for-loop).
With second for-loop you are trying to set radio buttons but you are using
variables not connected with this loop.
I am applying your code a little bit revised so when submitted $_POST will look: $_POS['1'] => choice value, $_POST['2'] => choice value...
where '1', '2'... are your question ids.

```
<?php
$choices = (choices());
$questions = (questions());
$questions_id = (questions_id());
$questions_length = count(questions());

echo '<form action="#" method="post">';

for ($i = 0; $i < $questions_length; $i++) {
    $each_q = $questions[$i];
    $each_q_id = $questions_id[$i];
?>


<div class="poll">
    <div class="poll_question">
        <?php echo $each_q_id . ". " . $each_q; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="poll_options">
        <div class="poll_option">


            <?php
                $each_c = $choices[$i];
                $question = $questions[$i];
                $choices_length = count($each_c);
                for ($k = 0; $k < $choices_length; $k++){

                $each_c = explode('<br />', $each_c);
            ?>

            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $each_q_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $choices[$i][$k]; ?>" id="c<?php echo $choices[$i][$k] ?>">
            <label for="c<?php echo $choices[$i][$k] ?>"><?php echo $choices[$i][$k]; ?></label>

            <?php
                }
                $data = $_POST;
                $each_cc = count($choices[$i]);
                print_r($session_user_id);
                $option = 0;
                if(isset($data[$each_q_id])){
                    $option = $data[$i];
                    echo "--" . $each_q_id . "--" . $each_cc . "--" . $option . "<br>";
                }
            ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
    echo '<input type=submit value="submit" />';
    echo '<br /></form><br /><br />';

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
       var_dump($_POST);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you're awesome, so far so good... I am just trying to get all choices to show for each question as right now it only shows the first choice for each question. But this works! (I will post the updated code once I have finished). Thank you so much again.

Comment: updated above, it's working and posts the result:

125--1--1--Somewhere we can talk-- ... etc etc. I will change the options variable to output the ID for the choice. Thanks again you helped me big time.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

This problem was solved by changing the code to the following:

```
<?php
$choices = (choices());
$questions = (questions());
$questions_id = (questions_id());
$questions_length = count(questions());

echo '<form action="#" method="post">';

for ($i = 0; $i < $questions_length; $i++) {
    $each_q = $questions[$i];
    $each_q_id = $questions_id[$i];
?>


<div class="poll">
    <div class="poll_question">
        <?php echo $each_q_id . ". " . $each_q; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="poll_options">
        <div class="poll_option">


            <?php
                $each_c = $choices[$i];   
                $each_c = explode('<br />', $each_c);
                $choices_length = count($each_c);
                for ($k = 0; $k < $choices_length; $k++){

            ?>


            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $each_q_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $each_c[$k]; ?>" id="<?php echo $each_c[$k] ?>">
            <label for="<?php echo $each_c[$k] ?>"><?php echo $each_c[$k]; ?></label>

            <?php
                }
                $data = $_POST;
                $each_cc = count($choices[$i]);
            //    print_r($session_user_id);
                $option = 0;
                if(isset($data[$each_q_id])){
                    $option = $data[$each_q_id];
                    echo $session_user_id . "--" . $each_q_id . "--" . $each_cc . "--" . $option . "--" . "<br>";
                }
            ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
    echo '<input type=submit value="submit" />';
    echo '<br /></form><br /><br />';

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
       var_dump($_POST);
    }
?>
```